# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{(tx)}}{x(x^2+1)}dx$

Tags: derivatives, improper-integrals, partial-derivative, self-learning, trigonometric-integrals

I want to show that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin{(tx)}}{x(x^2+1)}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}(1-e^{-t})\tag{1}$ for $t>0 $ by justifying differentiation under the integral sign and using $\displaystyle\int_R \frac{\cos{(tx)}}{x^2+1}=\pi e^{-|t|}$.

My attempt:-
Let $F(t)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{(tx)}}{x(x^2+1)}dx$.
If we try to compute $F'(t)$ for $t>0$ using differentiation under the integral sign, then we get

$$F'(t)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\sin{(tx)}}{x(x^2+1)}\right)\,dx=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos{(tx)}}{x^2+1}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-t}.\tag{2}$$

Now how to answer this question?

My hp 50g calculator unable to give answer using 'RISCH' and 'INTVX' commands
 If any member knows the answer may reply with correct answer.

Comment: Well (2) shouldn't be the same as (1) simply because you are supposed to integrate (2) w.r.t. $t$ to get (1).

Comment: Your question is exactly exercise 5 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf. Is that where it is coming from?

Comment: @Kcd, Yes, you are correct.Are you Kconrad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $t>0$, 2) gives $F(t)=\frac {\pi} 2 (1-e^{-t})$ by integration and the condition $F(0)=0$. (For $t <0$ you can use the fact that LHS of 1) is an odd function).