# Is there any approach using real methods to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin (x)}{x^{4}+1} d x$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

What is the approach to solve the integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin (x)}{x^{4}+1} d x$$

Is there any real methods to solve it?

Comment: I don't think it's a could idea to sue real methods.  The case will be thrown out of court. ;D

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$\frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \pi  \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Comment: i know the closed form of it using programs but i need the way not only the answer!!

Comment: One tedious method would be to break $x^4+1$ into some smaller pieces like $$x^4+1=(x^2+\sqrt 2x+1)(x^2-\sqrt 2x+1)$$ and using partial fractions.  (No guarantee that this method would arrive at the listed result in a reasonable time frame.)

Comment: A solution using complex analysis is given [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1117563p5122843).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let  $I(a) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin at} {t(t^2+1)}dt$. Then
$I’(a) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos at} {t^2+1}dt,\>
I’’(a)= \int_0^\infty \frac{t\sin at} {t^2+1}dt
$ and
$$I’’(a)-I(a) = -\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin at}t dt= -\frac\pi2$$
which leads to $I(a) = \frac\pi2 (1-e^{-a})$ and $I’(a) = \frac\pi2 e^{-a}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin x}{x^{4}+1} d x
= &\frac1{4\sqrt2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
( \underset{x-\frac1{\sqrt2} =t}{\frac{\sin x}{x^2-\sqrt2 x+1}} - \underset{x+\frac1{\sqrt2} =t}{\frac{\sin x}{x^2+\sqrt2 x+1}} ) d x\\
= &\frac1{4\sqrt2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\left( \frac{\sin(t+\frac1{\sqrt2})}{t^2+\frac12} - \frac{\sin(t-\frac1{\sqrt2})}{t^2+\frac12} \right) d t \>\>\>\>\>(\sqrt2t\to t)\\
=& \sin\frac1{\sqrt2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \frac t{\sqrt2}}{t^2+1} dt = \sin\frac1{\sqrt2}\cdot I’(\frac1{\sqrt2})\\
=&\frac\pi2 e^{-\frac1{\sqrt2} } \sin\frac1{\sqrt2} 
\end{align}

Comment: Linking another same integral: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3442116/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-sintxxx21dx